# HTML/CSS How do i remove the button icon

Tags: html, css, button

[image]

How do I remove the bottom left icon from the button to search.

```
<form action="search.php" method="POST">
                                        <input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search something..." required>
                                        <div id="close-icon"></div>
                                        <button type="submit" name="submit-search"></button>
                                    </form>
```

here is the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just trying to hide the tiny button on the bottom left? If so, this should sort you out!

```
<form action="search.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search something..." required>
    <div id="close-icon"></div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit-search" style="display:none"></button>
</form>
```

You can also do this in css using the following:

```
<style> 
.display-none { display:none; }
</style>

<form action="search.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search something..." required>
    <div id="close-icon"></div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit-search" class="display-none"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: In your sample there isn‘t a „display-none“ class.

Comment: Look at the 2nd code block in the style tag? 
"<style> .display-none { display:none; } </style>"

Comment: That‘s it. The style tag does not do anything. You‘re not havin‘ a class with the name ‚display-none‘ in your HTML. Furthermore i‘d recommend to not name classes like css attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but for enterprise level coding I've found it very useful. Please find this JS Fiddle link whereby the 2nd example is working perfectly and effectively hiding the button: https://jsfiddle.net/cpq3rwn1/